# Swagger java custom css

Tags: java, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Currently implementing swagger into a java based project. Swagger is added to the project during the build phase and packaged from maven. I would like to add some custom style to swagger. I see that there is some method CustomAsset, which allows you to insert custom assets into swagger. How can I override the SwaggerConfig in java to insert custom CSS?

```
c.CustomAsset("mylogo", thisAssembly, "YourWebApiProject.SwaggerExtensions.mylogo.png");
```

Is this possible without something like swashbuckle?

Comment: Hi,I am facing the same issue.Can you Please  tell solution for this??